# Sound level emissions (IEC 60704-1) spectrum?

Tags: acoustics, regulations, noise

I have a very noisy air conditioner that have a 10kHz peak at 75 dB, the rest (fan/compressor/pump) are under the regulation limit.

I would like to understand what is the measurement spectrum. I think 10kHz is out of the measurement spectrum, but I am not sure.

What is the procedure to measure household appliances noise level?

Comment: What *specifically* are you having trouble understanding? Re: "what is the procedure...", have you read the standard? Section 4 "Measurement methods and acoustical environments" lists several methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the measurement Spectrum?**

From BS EN 60704-1:2010+A11:2012 Page 10, Section 4.1 Paragraph 3

> The preferred noise emission quantity is the A-weighted sound power
>   level, LWA, in decibels

[image: Acoustic Weighting Curves]

**It is *not* correct to assume that a peak at 10kHz is outside the measurement range** - you can reduce your 75dB measurement by -2.5dB according to the curve shown above.

**What is the procedure?**

Page 11 Paragraph 1

> According to this standard, two principal methods exist, the direct
>   method and the comparison method, as described in 4.2 and 4.3 below.
>   These two methods can be used alternatively.

And then subsequently in Page 11 Section 4.2

> The direct method can be used only for measurements in qualified test environments
>   according to ISO 3744 for free field conditions over reflecting plane(s), and according to ISO
>   3743-2 for special reverberation test rooms.

and Page 11 Section 4.3

> The comparison method for measurement is explicitly described in ISO
>   3743-1 and in ISO 3743-2.